# Java: Cannot find package folder path

Tags: java

I have a project with the following package set up:

```
-src
   -Interface
   -Resources
      -images
```

I want to find the path to the Resources package folder. 
By using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()`, I am able to get to the images in the images folder but I also want to get the path for the folder Resources. As I do not know exactly what files will be there it is not possible to look for a determined resource. I am using the JFileChooser to enable the user to select the file, and the aim is to set the default directory to open in the Resources directory.

It works properly when running the project from NetBeans, but when I run the dist executable jar it does not find it as the path returned goes through the jar file. Any idea how to solve this situation?

So... I have been able to find the path returned whenever the project runs in Netbeans and when I run the dist jar. Follows the paths returned:

**netbeans:** *"Scheduler/Resources/"*

**dist:** *"Scheduler/Scheduler.jar!/Resources/"*

Comment: In your distributable jar, have you copied Resources folder with images? Where is your java class file located in this directory structure?

Comment: Also, what kind of paths are you using? Relative or Absolute?

Comment: Ok, so the class is in the Interface package and the folder I wan to get the path is the Resources package. BTW I did not explain properly and probably I could use a better organization with the packages names! Interface, Resources and Resources.images are all packages.

Comment: Noe, I am using relative paths I can get any resource in the packages, but I just want the package folder path as opposed to any resource.